# Mockito chain function usage

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

When I am mocking chain of methods do I have to write them in the below format only

```
when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(bar);
when(bar.getName()).thenReturn("Foo Bar");
```

or could I also use the below format? because both are working for me and I am asking this question because I was told that that my second (below) approach is wrong

```
when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(bar);
when(foo.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("Foo Bar");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mockito FAQ [addresses this explicitly](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-stub-chained-getters):

> ### Can I stub chained getters?
>
> ```
> when(mock.getA().getB()).thenReturn(...);
> ```
>
> This sort of stubbing, e.g. mock to return mock, to return mock, etc. should be used very sporadically, ideally never. It clearly points out violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). You don't want to mess with Demeter. Since you have been warned check out Mockito [deep stubs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS).

From a technical standpoint, it is supported, partially because it is indistinguishable from this:

```
when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(bar);
foo.getBar();
when(bar.getName()).thenReturn("Foo Bar");
```

...which can interfere with verification in the [hopefully-unlikely](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)) event that you need to `verify(foo, times(n)).getBar()`.

Comment: could you give me an instance or example where using them directly without distinctive mocking would be a problem. I am a newbie to the concept of mocking and mockito. so please bear my stupidity..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _distinctive_ mocking. My point is that if your test checks the number of times the method `foo.getBar()` was called, then chained stubbing will cause those numbers to be different.

Comment: I meant distinctive mocking as in mocking each method one step at a time. The first approach in my post. I also found a way to use  stubbing chain methods using  [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Answers.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)